# How to find all divs with specific ID using jQuery regular expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

In my document I've got several divs with ID beginning with letter "p" and then any number. I'd like to find them all using jQuery regular expression pattern and then add class to them. Can you help me fix this snippet? Thanks.

```js
$(function(){
  
  var pattern = "#p\d+";
  
  $(pattern).addClass(".red");
  
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.red {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="p27"></div>
<div id="p46"></div>
<div id="p124"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to apply any specific logic you need:

```js
$(function(){
      
  $("div")
      .filter(function() { return /^p\d+$/.test(this.id); })
      .addClass("red");
  
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: green;
}

.red {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="p27"></div>
<div id="nomatch"></div>
<div id="p124"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

`$("div").filter(function(i,e){return e.match(/^p\d+$/)!=null;}).addClass("red")`

It basically finds all divs, then filters out those that don't match the regular expression and adds the class to the remaining tags. (I have not tested this code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes this way:

```
$("div[id^='p']").addClass(".red");
```

Comment: this would return all `div` whose `id` start with `p` (*whether they have numbers or not after it*)

Comment: That's the simple solution I was looking for, thanks.